# Is there a reason why my file doesn't show any event markers?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, eeglab

I have exported an EDF file from BioTrace (a piece of software used to record EEG signals; EDF), and when I attempt to import it into MatLab's EEgLab, it says that there are no event markers (i.e. Events: none). I'm unfamiliar with MatLab, so I'm not sure if the issue is with the file, or just an issue with the user (me).

The example file that I'm using can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JNAOMQQ6UpjEHfGATcwjzcJElrbw9fGF/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Importing your file into eeglab with the BIOSIG toolbox (which is what I use for this type of files) gives me a dataset with 4 channels, sampled at 2046Hz, lasting 93 seconds, with 1 event (at the beginning). Does this sound like your file? If you should have more events or channels, I'd suggest to make sure it was recorded correctly or to try another file for verification.

This is the command I used to load the file:

```
EEG = pop_biosig('your_file.edf', 'importannot','off');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bossanova. The file should be approximately 75 minutes and contain hundreds of triggers. I've had the data run within EEGDisplay (a smaller, and lesser known signal processing platform), so I know the data was collected properly. I'll just keep working on it until i find a solution. Thanks anyway.